# What are the relevant criteria to compare neural nets with different hyper parameter settings?

Tags: neural-networks, hyperparameter

I want to compare different hyperparameter settings on the same network and the same task to get an impression of what works good and what works better. I am comparing different initializer, activation functions, optimizer, etc.

I am asking myself what are the relevant criteria to compare neural nets with different hyper parameter settings? Is it more then just:

- best validation accuricy
- number of epochs when best validation accuricy was reached
- time for each epoch (speed of training)

I would be happy for some input.

Thanks!

Comment: I'd like to add one more to the mix: **output fluctuations**. If the metric you chose fluctuates a lot from epoch to epoch or not.

Comment: @Djib2011: Thanks. Good idea. Do you have any idea about how to calculate this fluctuation?

Comment: I've never calculated it exactly, I've just noted it as an observation. For example one run might achieve the highest validation accuracy, but it fluctuates a lot more than another run.

Comment: I would say the relevant criteria depend entirely on the application, i.e. validation accuracy for medical diagnosis applicatoins, training speed perhaps important during the design period, and so on

Comment: @GR4 Yes you are right. And I am looking for a collection of all these criteria to compare hperparameter settings independent of the application.